# Git rebase edit and a few branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I had something like this:

```
     /-E-F - branch1
A-B-C - master
     \-X - branch2
```

After I have rebased to B and changed it on the master branch I got something like this:

```
     /-E-F - branch 
A-B-C
 \   \-X - branch2
  \-B*-C* - master
```

After that I have tried to rebase and edit in the same way B on the "branch" and I got something like this:

```
 /B**-C**-E-F - branch 
A-B-C
 \   \-X - branch2
  \-B*-C* - master
```

My intentions was to edit B for all branches and get something like this:

```
      /-E-F - branch1
A-B*-C - master
      \-X - branch2
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get back to the starting graph (take a look at commit recovery with reflog), it seems like it'd be easier to make the change to master and merge it (with --no-ff) into branch1 and branch2:

```
$ git checkout C
# make modifications
$ git commit
$ git checkout branch1
$ git merge --no-ff master
$ git checkout branch2
$ git merge --no-ff master

      /-E-F-G - branch1
     /     /
A-B-C-----D - master
     \     \  
      \-X---Y - branch2
```

Otherwise:

```
     /-E-F - branch1
A-B-C - master
     \-X - branch2

$ git checkout B
# make your modifications
$ git commit

     /-E-F - branch1
A-B-C - master
   \ \-X - branch2
    \-B*

$ git rebase --onto B* B branch1

     /-E-F
A-B-C - master
   \ \-X - branch2
    \-B*-C*-E*-F* - branch1

$ git rebase --onto C* master branch2

     /-E-F
A-B-C - master
   \ \-X
    \-B*-C*-E*-F* - branch1
          \-X* - branch2

$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard C*

     /-E-F
A-B-C
   \ \-X 
    \      /-E*-F* - branch1
     \-B*-C* - master
           \-X* - branch2
```